# Using Tensorflow Estimator for LSTMs to Accept Images

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to use Tensorflow's Estimator to simplify training using LSTM Networks. Apparently, to use tensorflow's Estimator, one must define a model function like so:

```
def some_model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    ...
```

I have no problem using placeholders to get the inputs and labels. How do I turn images into the shape accepted by tensorflow lstms which is [batch_size, num_time_steps, num_features]?

Comment: You need to flatten the images before feeding them into an LSTM unless you are implementing your own layer (like a convolutional/lstm). You can do that by `np.flatten()`. For `num_time_steps` you need to feed the LSTM with subsequent images (like a rolling window). If you are not processing sequential images that would help predicting the next one, you may be better of using a convolutional network or adapting an image flattening strategy (like feeding the row or column of pixels to LSTM in a sequence etc...)

Comment: The task is handwriting recognition and I'm feeding the image in vertical strips. I read the image first then I transpose it to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using numpy to load images to a multi-dimensional array. This does take quite a bit of memory, depending on the image sizes and the number of time steps.

Comment: What I'm asking is do I have to collapse the image dimensions to rnn dims or do I feed the images as they are read?

Comment: Yes, you have to ｒesize them. You can resize the images with cv2.resize or scipy.misc.imresize . If the features to your network are entered as a 1D vector, you can flatten the image after resizing.